# Change version php on OVH

Tags: php, remote-server, ovh

My problem is that i need to change the version of php from 4.4.9 to 5.5 on an remote server on http://www.ovh.com/

But i can't seem to be able to achieve this goal!

I have tried the recommended steps http://www.ovh.com/fr/g1207.configurer-php-web

And included the following .ovhconfig file:

```
app.engine=php
app.engine.version=5.5
http.firewall=none
environment=production
```

But when i check by phpinfo() or the command `php -v`, it says that i am using the php version 4.4.9

![enter image description here][1]

I am trying to run a Symfony application, which is not possible with a php of version lower than 5.3

How do i fix this problem ?

Comment: I'm now using Laravel and need use php5.6 minimum. I have 2 subdomain in my FTP. One is in php 5.3 (old website) and the other in php 5.6 (new website). When I read my answer below, I know everything I told you isn't right. I can update my answer. But are you still having this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a **`.htaccess`** file in **`/www/`** and write into :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5.5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
Header set cache-control "no-cache"
```

There is a **`.ovhconfig`** file (or create it) in the root of your FTP (before **`/www/`**) and write into :

```
app.engine=phpcgi
app.engine.version=auto

http.firewall=none
environment=development
```

Then go to the manager (v3 preferably because I'm not sure the function is available in the new interface yet) > `Hébergement` > `Gestion de l'Accélérateur Géocache` > `Appuyer sur Valider pour vider le cache`. (More explications [here](https://www.ovh.com/fr/g1290.geocache))

If this doesn't work, you should contact the OVH technical service.

Comment: i have added the .htaccess file with the content "SetEnv PHP_VER 5_5", but when i try the command `php -v` i still get the following output

PHP 4.4.9 (cgi) (built: Apr 20 2012 18:34:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies

**NOTE**: The .ovhconfig file is currently on the root folder.
Eg:
- www
  .ovhconfig
       -  sub files and folders 
(the dir www wnd .ovhconfig are in the same location)

Comment: i couldn't find the option Gestion du CDN, i added a screenshot in the answer, could you please have a look, and tell me if any of the options coincide with what you are talking about? This would be very helpful, i have been struggling with this problem for the past 3 weeks. Thank you

Comment: I made a mistake. It is not CDN, but : `Gestion de l'Accélérateur Géocache`

Comment: i have done the above and Emptied Cache as you suggested. But still for `php -v` i get the same result. PHP version 4.4.9.

Comment: any other suggestions ? Still stuck with same problem!

Answer (score 0):

OVH paths to different versions of PHP:

```
/usr/local/php5.3/bin/php  =>  PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Dec 10 2014 16:59:41)
/usr/local/php5.4/bin/php  =>  PHP 5.4.38 (cli) (built: Feb 26 2015 09:53:00)
/usr/local/php5.5/bin/php  =>  PHP 5.5.22 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2015 13:12:45)
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php  =>  PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2015 13:13:02)
/usr/local/php7.0/bin/php  =>  PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2016 10:58:42) ( NTS )
```

[(from this gist)](https://gist.github.com/floptwo/8867068)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, you can put `.ovhconfig` in the user root or the web root.
See https://docs.ovh.com/us/en/hosting/configuring-file-ovhconfig/

> If you host several websites on your hosting space, you have almost
> certainly configured a few Multisites. There are a number of reasons
> why you might decide to use a different PHP version on some of your
> Multisites.
>
> To do this, you must create an .ovhconfig file for the Multisite(s),
> containing the desired PHP version. You can refer to the instructions
> set out in the Editing the .ovhconfig file section of this guide, if
> necessary. When you download the .ovhconfig file to your storage
> space, be sure to do so inside the Multisite’s root folder. You can
> access the root folders through the OVHcloud Control Panel, under
> theMultisite tab of the relevant hosting plan.