# Laravel 5.1 and ovh Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, ovh

My host is the type pro (OVH)
I have a problem with laravel 5.1 in Ovh when I type `php artisan` I get

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/home/obliviushc/petite-enfance/artisan</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/home/obliviushc/petite-enfance/artisan</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
```

and as you see the version of php is 4.4.9
and i followed the instructions from the site of OVH to change the version of php 
and i added `.ovhconfig` in public/ file and it contains these lines

```
app.engine=php
app.engine.version=5.6
http.firewall=none
environment=production
```

and i tested inside a view file with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` 
and I get 5.6.15 
now is this due to the php of version or what ?
please help me I'm Stuck!

Comment: It seems that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30445226) was asked before, without being resolved. I looks like that configuration file does not affect the CLI. I suggest you take it up with the hosting provider, they are responsible to offer solutions here.

Comment: thanks man , That's what i see too the configuration seems to be in a place and the command line is another place , nothing affected

Comment: Jesus, they offer PHP 4? That's been unsupported for nearly a decade. Find a new host.

Comment: in browser you can see the version you want but in command line 
I see only 4.4.9

Comment: probably this is why, the path variable is still pointing to the old PHP version. And artisan run on command line.

Comment: tahnk you @MinaAbadir How Can I make it point to the new php version

Comment: would you run `which php` in command line?

Comment: I runned which php and the result is
/usr/local/bin/php

Comment: the result of <?php
echo PHP_BINDIR;
?>
is 
/usr/local/php5.6/bin

Comment: the problem now where I can find the path variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation), the minimum PHP version required is: `PHP >= 5.5.9`.

It seems the command line is still pointing to the old PHP version, so artisan fails. In order to get the correct path, find where your php is installed, add a script and run it from the browser (i.e. handled by Apache)

```
<?php
echo PHP_BINDIR;
```

Then add that directory to your PATH variable.

Finally try to remove the old PHP version path, you can find it by running this command in CLI:

```
which php
```

Comment: I successfully added php 5.6 of the new path but when I try to remove the old path i get can't delete read only

Comment: how do you try to remove it, also what is the output of `php -v` now?

Comment: I did rm /usr/local/bin/php  to remove ,,
the output is still 

PHP 4.4.9 (cgi) (built: Apr 20 2012 18:34:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies

Comment: This is not the right way, just add the new directory to the beginning of your PATH variable, so it's searched first.

Comment: You are the hero Man it worked  Thank you , but there is a little problem 
when I close Putty and enter again I find that the new path is deleted , how to save it ?

Comment: You need to add it to your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
php5.5 -v
```

if ok then use '**php5.5**' instead of '**php**' in every commands :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php5.5
php5.5 composer.phar install
php5.5 artisan clear-compiled
php5.5 artisan optimize
```

Comment: I discovered that ovh is not suitable with laravel I switched to forge with digital ocean

Comment: Ok with 1and1 for me. For OVH : https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/laravel-deploiement-ne-fonctionne-pas